Is there a %$% operator?
In  the book R for Data Science, there is an operator %$%, as in the example code below. But when I run that code, I get the error  message "there is no such operator". Can anyone help with this?
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %$%
  cor(disp, mpg)


It's a magrittr pipe. You must load the package with library(magrittr). This R-bloggers post might help.

This is a perfectly reproducible error, not a typo.  Why was it closed for those reasons?

The possible close reasons are a little bit coarse.  Could have been "failed to read chapter prerequisites carefully enough"

According to r-blogger, %$% is not exported from {tidyverse}, instead it is part of the magrittr package, so you will need to load {magrittr}.
install.packages("magrittr") # You only need to install it once. 
library(magrittr) 
mtcars %$%
  cor(disp, mpg)


You might also want to note in this answer that magrittr only needs to be installed once per R installation.

As said in prerequisites of the chapter, you need to load magrittr package explicitly if you want to use other pipe operators.
So, check if you have load the package:
library(magrittr)

